# Spring - save/restore HttpCookie (as a String) in a database gives problem: Last unit does not have enough valid bits

Tags: java, base64, httpcookie

My app needs to save and restore HttpCookie(s) in/from a database. So I tried to encode/decode HttpCookie objects to a String via the following code. The result is in some cases the error message: Last unit does not have enough valid bits.

Yes, I read post about the error, but that is about reading-via-a-buffer & converting-the-buffer. **This one is different, because the stream reading is in 1 go**!

In some cases, this code gives the mentioned error message. How can I solve this?

```
public class SerializableHttpCookie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6374381323722046732L;
    private transient HttpCookie cookie;
    private Field fieldHttpOnly; // needed for a workaround
    ...

public String encode2(HttpCookie cookie) {
    this.cookie = cookie;
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        outputStream.writeObject(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(  "IOException in encodeCookie", e);
        return null;
    }
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString( os.toByteArray());
}
public HttpCookie decode2(String encodedCookie) {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodedCookie);
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( bytes);
    HttpCookie cookie = null;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream( byteArrayInputStream);
        cookie = ((SerializableHttpCookie) objectInputStream.readObject()).cookie;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(   "IOException in decodeCookie", e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error(   "ClassNotFoundException in decodeCookie", e);
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

ReadObject and WriteObject are:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeObject(cookie.getName());
    out.writeObject(cookie.getValue());
    out.writeObject(cookie.getComment());
    out.writeObject(cookie.getCommentURL());
    out.writeObject(cookie.getDomain());
    out.writeLong(cookie.getMaxAge());
    out.writeObject(cookie.getPath());
    out.writeObject(cookie.getPortlist());
    out.writeInt(cookie.getVersion());
    out.writeBoolean(cookie.getSecure());
    out.writeBoolean(cookie.getDiscard());
    out.writeBoolean(getHttpOnly());
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    String name = (String) in.readObject();
    String value = (String) in.readObject();
    cookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);
    cookie.setComment((String) in.readObject());
    cookie.setCommentURL((String) in.readObject());
    cookie.setDomain((String) in.readObject());
    cookie.setMaxAge(in.readLong());
    cookie.setPath((String) in.readObject());
    cookie.setPortlist((String) in.readObject());
    cookie.setVersion(in.readInt());
    cookie.setSecure(in.readBoolean());
    cookie.setDiscard(in.readBoolean());
    setHttpOnly(in.readBoolean());
}
```

I used different approaches like the following resulting in errors as well (in the counting). The error is marked as comment.

```
private String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
    for (byte element : bytes) {
        int v = element & 0xff;
        if (v < 16) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character
                .digit(hexString.charAt(i + 1), 16)); // ERROR: hexString.charAt(i+1) out of range
    }
    return data;
}
```

**EncodeAndSerialize**

Another way of doing this is by calling the code in the Answer. Alas, I get the same error on decoding the string.

```
new SerializableHttpCookie2().serializeAndEncode(cookie)));
```

And

```
HttpCookie cookie = new SerializableHttpCookie2().decodeAndDeserialize(encodedCookie);
```

**Using the commons-codec library:**

```
public String serializeAndEncode(final HttpCookie cookie) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException {
    final String serialized = this.serialize(cookie);
    return new String( Hex.encodeHex(serialized.getBytes()));
}
```

And

```
public HttpCookie decodeAndDeserialize(final String string)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    // final String decoded = this.decode(string);
    String decoded;
    try {
        decoded = new String(Hex.decodeHex(string.toCharArray()));
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.deserialize(decoded);
}
```

Comment: Could you specify when the error occurs, for encode or for decode? And also some sample values for which it fails? Also your code for the second encoding solution would break for byte arrays of odd length . For example: when length is 5, indexes would be 0, 2, 4 and its breaks at 4 because s.charAt(5) doesnt exist.

Comment: The error occurs for decoding. I read the cookies from geocaching.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps the following class solves your problem

because `HttpCookie` doesnt implement `Serializable`, values are read and written back by reflection.

im using java 12 and in my case reflection triggers a warning, cause the code accesses `private final` fields. the warning says:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by HttpCookieDeSerializer (file:...) to field java.net.HttpCookie.name
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of HttpCookieDeSerializer
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

the class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.util.Base64;

public class HttpCookieDeSerializer {
    // TODO: need to be changed?
    private final String fieldValueDelimiter = "===";
    // TODO: need to be changed?
    private final String fieldValuePairDelimiter = "###";

    public HttpCookieDeSerializer() {
        super();
    }

    public String decode(final String string) {
        return new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(string));
    }

    public HttpCookie decodeAndDeserialize(final String string)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String decoded = this.decode(string);
        // TODO: remove sysout
        System.out.println(decoded);
        return this.deserialize(decoded);
    }

    public HttpCookie deserialize(final String decoded)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String name = this.preGet(decoded, "name");
        final String value = this.preGet(decoded, "value");
        final HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);
        final String[] fieldsAndValues = decoded.split("(" + this.fieldValuePairDelimiter + ")");
        for (final String fieldAndValue : fieldsAndValues) {
            final String[] fieldAndValueSplitted = fieldAndValue.split("(" + this.fieldValueDelimiter + ")");
            final Field field = HttpCookie.class.getDeclaredField(fieldAndValueSplitted[0]);
            if (Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) {
                // ???
                // continue;
            }
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final Class<?> type = field.getType();
            if (String.class.equals(type)) {
                field.set(cookie, this.convertNullStringToNullObject(fieldAndValueSplitted[1]));
            } else if (Long.TYPE.equals(type)) {
                field.setLong(cookie, Long.parseLong(fieldAndValueSplitted[1]));
            } else if (Integer.TYPE.equals(type)) {
                field.setInt(cookie, Integer.parseInt(fieldAndValueSplitted[1]));
            } else if (Boolean.TYPE.equals(type)) {
                field.setBoolean(cookie, Boolean.parseBoolean(fieldAndValueSplitted[1]));
            }
        }
        return cookie;
    }

    public String encode(final String string) {
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(string.getBytes());
    }

    public String serialize(final HttpCookie cookie) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        final Field[] fields = HttpCookie.class.getDeclaredFields();
        boolean first = true;
        for (final Field field : fields) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!first) {
                builder.append(this.fieldValuePairDelimiter);
            }
            builder.append(field.getName());
            builder.append(this.fieldValueDelimiter);
            final Class<?> type = field.getType();
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (String.class.equals(type)) {
                builder.append((String) field.get(cookie));
            } else if (Long.TYPE.equals(type)) {
                builder.append(Long.toString(field.getLong(cookie)));
            } else if (Integer.TYPE.equals(type)) {
                builder.append(Integer.toString(field.getInt(cookie)));
            } else if (Boolean.TYPE.equals(type)) {
                builder.append(Boolean.toString(field.getBoolean(cookie)));
            }
            first = false;
        }
        final String serialized = builder.toString();
        return serialized;
    }

    public String serializeAndEncode(final HttpCookie cookie) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException {
        final String serialized = this.serialize(cookie);
        // TODO: remove sysout
        System.out.println(serialized);
        return this.encode(serialized);
    }

    private Object convertNullStringToNullObject(final String string) {
        if ("null".equals(string)) {
            return null;
        }
        return string;
    }

    private String preGet(final String decoded, final String fieldName) {
        final String[] fieldsAndValues = decoded.split("(" + this.fieldValuePairDelimiter + ")");
        for (final String fieldAndValue : fieldsAndValues) {
            if (fieldAndValue.startsWith(fieldName + this.fieldValueDelimiter)) {
                return fieldAndValue.split("(" + this.fieldValueDelimiter + ")")[1];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final HttpCookieDeSerializer hcds = new HttpCookieDeSerializer();
        try {
            final HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie", "first");
            final String serializedAndEncoded = hcds.serializeAndEncode(cookie);
            // TODO: remove sysout
            System.out.println(serializedAndEncoded);
            final HttpCookie other = hcds.decodeAndDeserialize(serializedAndEncoded);
            // TODO: remove sysout
            System.out.println(cookie.equals(other));
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in my mind there is no need to encode/and or hex the serialization-string.

but if you want to do so, i suggest to use apache commons-codec library's `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` cause its a tested and stable lib without runtime-dependencies at the size of ~331kb

never the less, ive tried the following possibilities of serializing and deserializing

1. without base64-encoding/hexing
2. with base64-encoding
3. with hexing
4. with base-64-encoding and hexing

for me, all possibilities work fine.

Comment: Alas, gives the same error. In my original question I added the code (under "EncodeAndSerialize" for encoding and decoding.

Comment: ok, what do you want to achive? java.net.HttpCookie cant be written with ObjectOutputStream, respectively ByteArrayOutputStream, cause its not marked as Serializable and its a final class that denies inheritance. so, in my mind reflection in combination with your own serialization-strategy is the only way to get this done. if you want to hex and/or unhex a String or char[], why dont you make use of org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex?